# How to change the height of panel in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the height of bootstrap panel,I searched for the same on stackoverflow but did not find anything related.The image that I have given below shows the panel but it is colliding with the footer and hiding the buttons.

[image]

Comment: Its not very clear what do you want, plus, you should include part of the code you have so far, so we can check it and find solutions. What do you mean with bootstrap panel ? Which buttons are hidden ?

Comment: yes, please show is some code!